# nx serve is ignoring import of "@angular/localize/init"

Tags: angular, internationalization, nrwl-nx

I am trying to implement `@angular/localize` in my project which is part of an Nx workspace (nx@16.4.3). I am following the official guide: https://angular.io/guide/i18n-overview

Specifically, I

- installed the version of `@angular/localize@16.1.3` which aligns with my current angular version
- added `import '@angular/localize/init'` to my polyfills.ts
- added `/// <reference types="@angular/localize" />` to my main.ts
- added i18n configuration to my project config:

  ```
  "i18n": {
    "sourceLocale": "en",
    "locales": {
      "de": {
        "translation": "apps/web/login/src/locale/messages.de.xlf"
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- configured the build target

  ```
  ...
  "aot": true,
  "localize": ["de"]
  ...
  ```

When I `nx serve` this project, I am expecting to have my strings localize in `de`. However, I get the the following error

> Error: It looks like your application or one of its dependencies is using i18n.
> Angular 9 introduced a global `$localize()` function that needs to be loaded.
> Please run `ng add @angular/localize` from the Angular CLI.
> (For non-CLI projects, add `import '@angular/localize/init';` to your `polyfills.ts` file.

When I inspect my polyfills.js bundle file, I see that webpack apparently ignores the import of `@angular/localize/init` which explains the missing $localize function in the app.

```
...
/***/ 85028:
/*!****************************************!*\
  !*** @angular/localize/init (ignored) ***!
  \****************************************/
/***/ (() => {

/* (ignored) */

/***/ }),
...
```

How can I make webpack not ignore this import and make this work?

Extracting the tags using `@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n` works perfectly fine.

I tried to reinstall node_module to make sure versions are correct and also looked up github issues in order to find answers - without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record: I was running into a problem where an outdated browserslist configuration prevented it to work: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/48194

basically I had configured `safari >= 12` whereas angular officially supports only the latest two major versions. I changed that to `safari >= 15` and now everything works.

only took me 7 days of research...